# Sort a list of words alphabetically and filter by first letter

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have this problem and I dont know where to start.
For example I have this in my database [this is just sample database
]

```
id  word
1   adore
2   and
3   apple
4   asore
5   banana
6   bate
7   beat
8   busy
```

How can I sort it and filter it so I only view words beginning with 'A'?

```
id  word
1   adore
2   and
3   apple
4   asore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, word 
from your_table
where word like 'a%'
order by id
```

or

```
select id, word 
from your_table
where substring(word, 1, 1) = 'a'
order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL-LIKE-Statement.

SQL: `SELECT DISTINCT word FROM Table WHERE word LIKE 'A%'`
This only returns words that start with an a.

Answer (score 1):

This is lot simpler than you think. You can use [SQL LIKE operator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm).

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE word LIKE 'a%' ORDER BY word;
```